# How to retrieve the value of the URL from where a request is performed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, request

I am using Ruby on Rails (3.2.2) and I would like to retrieve the value of the URL from where a request is performed. That is, given I am on the `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147789` Web page and in that page content there is an link having a URL to my application at `http://my_application.com`, when I access that URL I would like to retrieve the `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147789` string.

**Is it possible? If so, how?**

Comment: You might try `request.referer` within your controller. But not sure yet, not on my machine yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can use [HTTP_REFERER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

```
request.referer
```

Comment: BTW: Is the `request.referer` string always "set"/"generated" and available for any request performed from any source?